# How to connect vb.net to wamp server?

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, wampserver

Do you know of any way on how to connect wampserver or phpmyadmin localhost to vb.net.
I mean adding, searching, deleting, updating, listing of data from the localhost database via vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge tutorial about VB.net and MySQL:
http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-1

Smaller tutorial about VB.net and MySQL:
http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AccessMySqlDatabase04252005015856AM/AccessMySqlDatabase.aspx

Comment: I mean the procedure on how to do it in vb.net, will I add a database file?or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all install mysql-connector-net-6.0.7 and follow this:

Right click on the program and add reference then browse then mysql.data.dll
then add module

Name it connection and copy this codes

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module connection
    Public conn As New MySqlConnection

```
Public Sub ConnectDatabase()

    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server=Dell-PC;Data Source=localhost:3306;Database=dbquicklend;User ID=root;"
            conn.Open()
        End If

    Catch myerror As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in Database Connection", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub DisconnectDatabase()
    Try
        conn.Close()
    Catch myerror As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Module

just call connectdatabase anywhere in the program you would like to connect or call disconnectdatabase when you need to disconnect